# Encode letter to number

Tags: javascript, string, decode, encode

I feel like I am failing everything this semester. but I was wondering if you all could help me with a JS project. We have been tasked with essentially converting numbers to letters and vica versa using textareas in HTML. I was able to do the numbers to letters function, but am having difficulties going the other way. what I have for all is:

```
var $ = function(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};
window.onload = function() {
    $("btnDecode").onclick = fnDecode;
    $("btnEncode").onclick = fnEncode;
    $("btnClear").onclick = fnClear;
};
function fnDecode() {
var msg = $("textin").value;
if (msg === "") {
    $("textin_span").innerHTML = "* Please enter a message to decode *";
    $("textin").focus;
    return;
} else {
    $("textin_span").innerHTML = "";
}
var nums = msg.split(",");
var outstr = "";

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    var n2 = parseInt(nums[i]);
    if (isNaN(n2)) {
        outstr += "?";
    } else if (isNallN(nums[i])) {

    } else if (n2 === 0) {
        outstr += " ";
    } else if (n2 < 1 || n2 > 26) {
        outstr += "?";
    } else {
        outstr += String.fromCharCode(n2+64);
    }
    $("textout").value = outstr;
    }
}

function isNallN(s) {
    //parse string to check all characters are digits
}

function fnEncode() {
var msg = $("textin").value.toUpperCase();
$("textin").value = msg;
if (msg === "") {
    $("textin_span").innerHTML = "* Please enter numberse to decode *";
    $("textin").focus;
    return;
} else {
    $("textin_span").innerHTML = "";
}
var c;
var outstr = "";


for (var i=0; i<msg.length; i++);
    c = msg.charCodeAt(i);
    if (typeof c === "number") {
        outstr += "99";
    }else if (c === " ") {
        outstr += 0;
    /*} else if (c[i] >= "A" && c[i] <= "Z") {
        outstr += "99";*/
    } else {
        outstr += String.charCodeAt(c - 64);
    }
    $("textout").value = outstr;
    //var x = msg.charAT(i);

}
```

obviously isNallN is not complete, but he promised us if we could figure out fnEncode we should be able to do isNallN with no issues (which I am hoping is true lol) What am doing wrong though in fnEncode? Every time I run it, it gives me  "99" even when I put letters in.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ with your html and javascript so it would be easier to debug?

Comment: Of course. https://jsfiddle.net/jlamember829/pL1eghxq/1/ 
for some reason though decode is not working there, yet it works when I run it from netbeans into chrome.

Comment: How do you expect jsfiddle to load the `<script src="translate.js"></script>` resource?

Comment: I am not familiar with jsfiddle. translate.js is what is in the javascript section. do I not need it in there?

Comment: @NathanContini yes please add it in there as well. Or add the code from it in the `script` section.

Comment: `msg.charCodeAt(i)` does always return a number. What is `typeof c === "number"` supposed to test for?

Comment: I am so sorry. I know I am doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what it is. I hit the drop down in the javascript section, and input src="translate.js" but it still isn't working. Or am I doing that wrong as well? You guys are being so amazing helping me, and I feel like an idiot over here.

Comment: @Bergi that is to test to see if they input a number and not a letter, it should throw an error showing "99"

Comment: @NathanContini Uh, no. `charCodeAt` always (for valid indices) returns an integer, the character code. To check whether that character is a digit, you should use `msg[i] >= '0' && msg[i] <= '9'`.

Comment: @Bergi I apologize I did not explain it properly. for the encode function, the user should be able to put in letters, and in the bottom text area, the matching number should appear. ie if they type ABC, then in teh bottom box 123 appears. the opposite happens on the decode function, where if they type numbers and clicked decode, letters appear. But with either option, if you put numbers and click encode, it is supposed to throw the up 99 like the decode function, which throws a ? if you put in anything that is not a number.